# ¿Por qué no se imprime 'a' o 'b'?

Tags: go

Me encontré con [esto](https://play.golang.org/p/SFsC2Sibrw) en Golang y el resultado no es tan obvio para mí, acá el código:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 'a'
    b := a | 'b'
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

¿Se imprime `a`? ¿Se imprime `b`?

No, el resultado en la consola es `99`, ¿por qué?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira, `a` en codigo ASCII es `97` y `b` en ASCII es `98`.

Al hacer el `OR` estás haciendo el `OR` de `97` y `98` en binario, es decir,

`1100001 OR 1100010`  = `1100011`, es decir `99`.

Edit: Si al resultado lo imprimes dandole formato, en vez de mostrar el código ascii vemos que muestra la `c` (valor ascii `99`)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 'a'
    b := a | 'b'
    fmt.Printf("%+q", b)
}
```

*He cambiado el println por printf y le he dado formato